# How do I enable WiFi channels 12 and 13 on Linux?

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-device-driver

I want to enable channels 12 and 13. I realise there are regulations in certain countries, but I would like to be able to manually select and have the responsibility fall on me as a person.

```
$ iw phy
```

[snip]

```
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
```

Answer (score 1):

`% iw reg set <country code here, e.g. JP>`

Read [this](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory/CRDA) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, although this only causes it to become more restrictive (it takes the lowest common denominator) rather than unlocking the channels of the new regulatory zone. Just wondering if there's any low-level method to bypass this.

Comment: unfortunately this does work for me.  Setting the country code enables the freq. range enabled (`iw reg get`) but somehow the bands remain disabled (`iw list`).